# postgres column "X" does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-literals

I have this postgrse code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS config_change_log
(
  id                    serial primary key,
  last_config_version   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  is_done               Boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  change_description     varchar(255),
  timestamp timestamp   default current_timestamp
);

INSERT INTO config_change_log(last_config_version, is_done, change_description )
VALUES("5837-2016-08-24_09-12-22", false, "{ 'key':'value'}");
```

and I get this error:

```
psql:createConfigChangeLog.sql:11: ERROR:  column "5837-2016-08-24_09-12-22" does not exist
LINE 2: VALUES("5837-2016-08-24_09-12-22", false, "{ 'key':'value'}"...
```

how can it be? it's a value not a column.postgr

Comment: Use single quotes, rather than double quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `single quotes` for string constants

```
INSERT INTO config_change_log(last_config_version, is_done, change_description )
VALUES('5837-2016-08-24_09-12-22', false, '{ ''key'':''value''}');
```

Also you can escape `single quotes` in data by doubling them

- [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/972a4/1)