# ERROR: syntax error at or near "a2e3916c" LINE 1: a2e3916c-dce2-11ec-a644-16e7866bc173 ^ SQL state: 42601 Character: 1

Tags: postgresql, string-constant

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9MPg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhTlD.png)

CAN YOU PLEASE SOLVE MY QUERY? I AM GETTING ERRORS AGAIN AND AGAIN

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Unless you have some weird Unicode characters instead of `"` there, that should work as is…

Comment: @deceze: no it shouldn't. String constants have to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL (`'`), double quotes (`"`) are for identifiers (e.g. column names)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39474081/postgres-column-x-does-not-exist

Comment: @a_horse Right, didn't pay attention to the [tag:postgresql] tag.

Comment: @deceze: well that has nothing to do with "Postgres" - this is how it was defined in the SQL standard over 40 years ago.

Comment: @a_horse But certain other implementations don't really care too much about it…

Comment: @deceze: it's not Postgres' fault if other implementations ignore syntax rules that are older than those implementations.